# Unable to 'make' android ndk project - build fails: [build-openh264-x86] Error 2

Tags: android, build, makefile, ffmpeg, android-ndk

I've attempted these two fixes I've found while researching the issue:

```
android update project  --23 --/Users/ajswann/Downloads/android-sdk-macosx 

make OS=android NDKROOT=/Users/ajswann/Downloads/android-sdk-macosx TARGET=android-19 ARCH=x86 clean
```

...however neither seems to resolve the issue.

Any input/suggestions are appreciated.

P.S.

I'm running OSX - could this be an issue with attempting to run an x86 architecture on a 64 bit machine?

### Error Message:

```
chris-mini-mac:linphone-android ajswann$ sudo make
ls: /opt/local/etc/openssl/certs: No such file or directory
/Users/ajswann/Downloads/android-sdk-macosx/tools/android update project --path . --target android-23
Updated project.properties
Updated local.properties
build.xml: Found version-tag: custom. File will not be updated.
Updated file ./proguard-project.txt
It seems that there are sub-projects. If you want to update them
please use the --subprojects parameter.
/Users/ajswann/Downloads/android-sdk-macosx/tools/android update test-project --path tests -m .
Resolved location of main project to: /groupchat/linphone-android/tests
Updated project.properties
Updated local.properties
Updated file tests/proguard-project.txt
Updated ant.properties
/Users/ajswann/Downloads/android-sdk-macosx/tools/android update project --path liblinphone_tester --target android-23
Updated project.properties
Updated local.properties
Updated file liblinphone_tester/proguard-project.txt
ant -e -S clean
Buildfile: /groupchat/linphone-android/build.xml
No sub-builds to iterate on
mkdir -p /groupchat/linphone-android/submodules/externals/openh264/include/wels
rsync -rvLpgoc --exclude ".git"  /groupchat/linphone-android/submodules/externals/openh264/codec/api/svc/* /groupchat/linphone-android/submodules/externals/openh264/include/wels/.
building file list ... done

sent 156 bytes  received 20 bytes  352.00 bytes/sec
total size is 56216  speedup is 319.41
mkdir -p /groupchat/linphone-android/submodules/externals/build/openh264
mkdir -p /groupchat/linphone-android/submodules/externals/build/openh264/arm
cd /groupchat/linphone-android/submodules/externals/build/openh264/arm \
    && rsync -rvLpgoc --exclude ".git"  /groupchat/linphone-android/submodules/externals/openh264/* .
building file list ... done

sent 18841 bytes  received 20 bytes  37722.00 bytes/sec
total size is 48272799  speedup is 2559.40
cd /groupchat/linphone-android/submodules/externals/build/openh264/arm && \
    make libraries -j4 OS=android ARCH=arm NDKROOT=/Users/ajswann/Downloads/android-ndk-r10e TARGET=android-19
cd ./ && sh ./codec/common/generate_version.sh
Keeping existing codec/common/inc/version_gen.h
mkdir -p /groupchat/linphone-android/submodules/externals/build/openh264
mkdir -p /groupchat/linphone-android/submodules/externals/build/openh264/x86
cd /groupchat/linphone-android/submodules/externals/build/openh264/x86 \
    && rsync -rvLpgoc --exclude ".git"  /groupchat/linphone-android/submodules/externals/openh264/* .
building file list ... done

sent 18841 bytes  received 20 bytes  12574.00 bytes/sec
total size is 48272799  speedup is 2559.40
cd /groupchat/linphone-android/submodules/externals/build/openh264/x86 && \
    make libraries -j4 OS=android ARCH=x86 NDKROOT=/Users/ajswann/Downloads/android-ndk-r10e TARGET=android-19
cd ./ && sh ./codec/common/generate_version.sh
nasm -DX86_32 -f elf -I./codec/common/x86/   -o codec/decoder/core/x86/dct.o codec/decoder/core/x86/dct.asm
codec/decoder/core/x86/dct.asm:1: error: label or instruction expected at start of line
codec/decoder/core/x86/dct.asm:144: error: label or instruction expected at start of line
codec/decoder/core/x86/dct.asm:234: error: symbol `IdctResAddPred_mmx' redefined
codec/decoder/core/x86/dct.asm:262: error: symbol `WelsBlockZero16x16_sse2' redefined
codec/decoder/core/x86/dct.asm:276: error: symbol `WelsBlockZero8x8_sse2' redefined
codec/decoder/core/x86/dct.asm:287: error: label or instruction expected at start of line
make[1]: *** [codec/decoder/core/x86/dct.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
Keeping existing codec/common/inc/version_gen.h
make[1]: *** wait: No child processes.  Stop.
make: *** [build-openh264-x86] Error 2
```

Source Repository (I simply clone it, add the platform-tools and tools folder from my android-sdk and run 'make' and I get this error):

https://github.com/TheBaobabTeam/linphone-android